# Performing operations after styling in a dataframe

Tags: pandas

I have 2 dataframes df1 and df2. I am trying to apply styling on df1, then drop a column from it and then finally concatenate with df2. Styling on df1 should be retained, though its being lost

I am using the code as listed below, though doesn't seem to work

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([["A", 1],["B", 2]], columns=["Letter", "Number"])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([["A", 1],["B", 2]], columns=["Letter2", "Number2"])

def highlight(s):
    return ['background-color: red']*2

df1 = df1.style.apply(highlight)
df1.data = df1.data.drop('Letter', axis=1)


combined = pd.concat([df1.data, df2],sort=True)   

with pd.ExcelWriter('testcolor.xlsx') as writer: 
    combined.to_excel(writer,sheet_name = 'test')
```

I am expecting "Number" from df1 to be highlighted red and Letter2 and Number2 to be in original colour